# 403 Forbidden while using postman & python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, cloudflare, http-status-code-403

Actually, I am trying to collect some stock data from API.
It returns a success response of 200 while using the browser. But once I tried to call via Postman or Python script, it returns **403 FORBIDDEN**.

As per my understanding so far, this API doesn't require a token or authorization because you can call the API directly from the browser.

Here's the API Url:

https://idx.co.id/umbraco/Surface/TradingSummary/GetStockSummary?Length=3&date=20220714

Here's the website:

https://idx.co.id/data-pasar/ringkasan-perdagangan/ringkasan-saham/

I have tried several ways, but it doesn't solve my issue:

- I already put User-Agent & Accept.
- Put authorization, put token doesn't help.
- Curl this API also doesn't help much.

[postman][image: 1]

[curl][image: 2]

[python][image: 3]

```
import requests
parameters = {
    "Length": 2,
    "date": 20220714
}
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
}
base_url = "https://idx.co.id/umbraco/Surface/TradingSummary/GetStockSummary"
response = requests.get(url = base_url, params = parameters, headers = headers)
response
```

Comment: 403 means forbidden, are you sure you dont need to provide credentials in headers["Authorization"], like a token ?

Answer (score 1):

> As per my understanding so far, this API doesn't require token or authorization because you can call the API directly from browser.

It is still possible that you require some token/cookie in the background that you need to add to your header. For example CSRF tokens if you are filling out a form.

In your browser development tools, look into the network tab and inspect the request. There you can see a cookie named `__cf_bm` which seems to come from Cloudflare.

Assuming that this cookie is only set on the main page, you could try to use a session to first acquire the cookie, then request the api.

```py
import requests


session = requests.session()
main_url = 'https://idx.co.id/'
api_url = 'https://idx.co.id/umbraco/Surface/TradingSummary/GetStockSummary?Length=3&date=20220714'


# Getting the cookie
session.get(main_url)

# Requesting the api endpoint
result = requests.get(api_url)
```

But this still results in `You do not have access to idx.co.id`. The anti bot system of Cloudflare recognizes that you are not in a browser. It is possible that you need to have javascript enabled to get a valid cookie. I would recommend to use [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) to have javascript enabled.

Comment: AFAICT, Cookies don't seem to be needed.

Comment: It won't probably help you with this specific issue, but you shouldn't use a Surface controller to expose an API. Inherit from UmbracoApiController instead.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Setting Gear icons on Postman.
Click and Select `Settings` from the dropdown menu.
In the Settings, Select `Proxy`
Check the `Add a custom proxy configuration` checkbox
In the Proxy Bypass Area box, if using Mac or Linux Os, Enter 127.0.0.1

Close the settings and restart Postman
In the POST, use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` when specifying your endpoint to send.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if Postman is out of date. If it is you can update Postman by clicking gear icon, `Settings > Update` and click the orange button.

My API call wasn't working and after updating it works.